# Drupal Block user from login for X days

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Is there any module which block/truncate the user from login for X(say 5) days.

It should shows notification "You have been blocked for 5 days by moderator" or something like that.

Thanks,

Edvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On what condition you want block him?

Here's module for blocking: [ban_unpublish](http://drupal.org/project/ban_unpublish) and i assume [there's](http://drupal.org/project/modules?text=user+blocking) more modules for that.

But i prefer [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), where you can set rules on conditions to block users...